# Issue with summernote saving the textarea value when dynamically injected

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, summernote

So i am having trouble sending the value of the textareas that are dynamically generated and have summernote applied to them.

Here is a link that will reproduce the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/jk6pjnt7/1/

so basically, i am trying to add a new textarea dynamically when i click the "add Step-textarea" because i don't know how many "step" the user will need. the problem is that when i submit the form, i won't get the value of the new textarea. they will have a blank value.

If i do the same and i remove summernote plugin form the process everything works fine.

I have this small pice of coed that prevents the form from submitting and will display what would be submitted in the console, so you might need to open your devtools to see the debugging info.

```
 $('form').submit(function () {
    //console.log($(this));
    console.info($('form').serializeArray())
    return false;

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the DOM is being dynamically changed, we cannot 'watch' these new elements in the typical way. In jquery what we use is called delegation and in particular [jQuery.fn.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/). We bubble up from the dynamically altered container (in this case, being `<form>`) to an element that will exist and guaranteed not to change. In this specific case in particular, your line `$(next_input).val('');` I changed to `$(next_input).html('');` as we're dealing with delegated `textarea`'s which work a bit differently from input boxes in the way they take data.

Here is the fixed code: http://jsfiddle.net/jk6pjnt7/3/